# Linq Query return Anonymous Type Error

Tags: entity-framework, linq, wcf

I trying to developing banking system . I trying to join three tables records into single table . but the problem is when i compile it i got following errors.

> Error CS1929  'IOrderedQueryable<>' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload
>   'ParallelEnumerable.Concat<>(ParallelQuery<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<>

Here is my Linq Query .

```
  public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {

    var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new
            {
                w.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                w.Date
            }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
            {
                d.Account_Number,
                Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                d.Date
            })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
         .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
         {
             //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
             Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
             Deposit = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
             Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
            e.Account_Fees
         }));


                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
            }
        }
    }


This is DBContext class.

 public partial class HalifaxDatabaseEntities : DbContext
    {
        public HalifaxDatabaseEntities()
            : base("name=HalifaxDatabaseEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Web_User_login> Web_User_login { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<USER> USERS { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<tblUser> tblUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Holder_Details> Current_Account_Holder_Details { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Details> Current_Account_Details { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Deposit> Current_Account_Deposit { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Current_Account_Withdraw> Current_Account_Withdraw { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the Model Class ..
[image]

Here is the Result i Expect when i clicked the account number its should display the specific record [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to create the same schema / class as output for every participant for the `Concat`, here since two anonymous types are never same, therefore it will always fail, `Concat` needs same / consistent Type `T`, check the details underneath:

`IEnumerable<T>` needs `IEnumerable<T>` for the Concat call, so Type `T` remains consistent, which is not possible for the anonymous types, check the definition [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx), its like:

`public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second
)`

```
class Account
{
   public int? Account_Number {get;set;}

   public decimal? Deposit {get;set;}

   public decimal? Withdrawal {get;set;}

   public decimal? Account_Balance {get;set;}

   public DateTime? Date {get;set;}
}

public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
{

    var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
    using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
    {

        var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(w => new Account
        {
            Account_Number = w.Account_Number
,
            Deposit = (decimal?)null,

            Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount
,
            Date  = w.Date
        }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new Account
        {
            Account_Number = d.Account_Number
        ,
            Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount
        ,
            Withdrawal = (decimal?)null
        ,
            Date = d.Date
        })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
        .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new Account
        {
            Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
            Account_Balance = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance

        }));


        var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. You are trying to `Concat` different anonymous types.

```
var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Select(w => new
    {
        Account_Number = w.Account_Number
        ,
        Deposit = (decimal?)null,

        Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount
        ,
        Date = w.Date
    }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Select(d => new
    {
        Account_Number = d.Account_Number
        ,
        Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount
        ,
        Withdrawal = (decimal?)null
        ,
        Date = d.Date
    })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
    .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Select(e => new
    {
        //You should perform same anonymous type which you want to concat
        Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
        Deposit = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
        Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
        Date = null
    }));
```

Also, I don't know requirements and details but are you sure about using the `Concat` ? It seems that you need to create `join` instead of `Concat`. If the entities have navigation properties, I strongly suggest you to use them.

Comment: Do you have navigation properties ? It exactly satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Firstly, before building queries you should decorate the EF context with navigation properties and then you can retrieve the desired data easily. There is a perfect tutorial here. Check it. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx